# How to take generate conditional group mean?

Tags: r, dataframe

In the below data set, I would like to create the group mean of X when a given observation's `Y` value is greater than 10 (where the grouping variable is `Team`). So the new column should indicate the group average of the x values when the y value is greater than 10.

I can easily create the group mean with dplyr:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  mutate(GroupMean = mean(X))
```

However, I don't know how to do this while adding an additional condition. The way I've been working around it is just by subsetting then joining the results back into the original data, but such a process is remarkably inefficient.

This is my initial data set:

```
structure(list(Team = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), X = c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 
13L, 3L), Y = c(1L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 10L, 
9L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

I would like it to become:

```
structure(list(Team = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), X = c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 
13L, 3L), Y = c(1L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 10L, 
9L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 12L), GroupMean = c(12.67, 12.67, 12.67, 
12.67, 12.67, 12.67, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: In your expected output for `Team = A` you get 12.67 as output which is mean of `Y` when `Y > 10`.

Comment: My mistake. I accidentally wrote in the mean of the Y value instead of the X. It should be 4.33. I also should have put in 8 for Team B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the `X` values where `Y > 10`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(Team) %>% mutate(GroupMean = mean(X[Y > 10]))

#   Team      X     Y GroupMean
#   <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>
# 1 A         2     1      4.33
# 2 A         4    11      4.33
# 3 A         3    12      4.33
# 4 A         6    15      4.33
# 5 A         7     7      4.33
# 6 A         3     7      4.33
# 7 B         6     5      8   
# 8 B         4     6      8   
# 9 B         7     5      8   
#10 B         8    11      8   
#11 B         1    10      8   
#12 B         2     9      8   
#13 C         4     2      3   
#14 C         6     2      3   
#15 C        12     9      3   
#16 C        10     4      3   
#17 C        13     5      3   
#18 C         3    12      3
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to add a second condition, could I just add a '&' operator and another logical test inside the square brackets?

Comment: Yes. Example - `mean(X[Y > 10 & X > 2])`

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, GroupMean := mean(X[Y > 10]), .(Team)]
```